# Intuitive meaning of $L_X\omega$

Tags: differential-forms

Suppose $\alpha$ is a one form and $\omega$ is two form such that 
$$\alpha= \omega(X,.)\text{ for some } X$$
Then what does intutive meaning of the following expression 
$$L_X\omega= \omega$$

Comment: What was the point of introducing $\alpha$?